# Can NodeJS Puppeteer printed PDF have feature like HTML's <a> or Adobe's Hyperlink to jump to other part on PDF?

Tags: node.js, hyperlink, puppeteer, page-jump

I would like to use NodeJS Puppeteer to prepare PDF that support page jumping from Summary Page. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

there is no adequate way to do that, but if you know the list format (a4/a3/a2) and letter height in the table of contents, you can calculate the pixel position of any hyperlink you want and click it with
`page.mouse.click(x, y[, options])`

Answer (score 0):

It is support by using `<a>` with adding below css:

```
@media print {
    a::after{
      content: " (" attr(href) ") ";
    }
  }
```